# Increase/Decrease audio volume using FFmpeg

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, volume

I'm am currently using C# invokes to call the FFmpeg APIs to handle video and audio.  I have the following code in place to extract the audio from a video and write it to a file.

```
while (ffmpeg.av_read_frame(formatContext, &packet) >= 0)
{
    if (packet.stream_index == streamIndex)
    {
        while (packet.size > 0)
        {
            int frameDecoded;
            int frameDecodedResult = ffmpeg.avcodec_decode_audio4(codecContext, frame, &frameDecoded, packet);

            if (frameDecoded > 0 && frameDecodedResult >= 0)
            {
                //writeAudio.WriteFrame(frame);

                packet.data += totalBytesDecoded;
                packet.size -= totalBytesDecoded;
            }
        }

        frameIndex++;
    }

    Avcodec.av_free_packet(&packet);
}
```

This is all working correctly.  I'm currently using the FFmpeg.AutoGen project for the API access.

I want to be able to increase/decrease the volume of the audio before its written to the file, but I cannot seem to find a command or any help with this.  Does it have to be done manually?

**Update 1:**

After receiving some help, this is the class layout I have:

```
public unsafe class FilterVolume
{
    #region Private Member Variables

    private AVFilterGraph* m_filterGraph = null;
    private AVFilterContext* m_aBufferSourceFilterContext = null;
    private AVFilterContext* m_aBufferSinkFilterContext = null;

    #endregion

    #region Private Constant Member Variables

    private const int EAGAIN = 11;

    #endregion

    public FilterVolume(AVCodecContext* codecContext, AVStream* stream, float volume)
    {
        CodecContext = codecContext;
        Stream = stream;
        Volume = volume;

        Initialise();
    }

    public AVFrame* Adjust(AVFrame* frame)
    {
        AVFrame* returnFilteredFrame = ffmpeg.av_frame_alloc();

        if (m_aBufferSourceFilterContext != null && m_aBufferSinkFilterContext != null)
        {
            int bufferSourceAddFrameResult = ffmpeg.av_buffersrc_add_frame(m_aBufferSourceFilterContext, frame);
            if (bufferSourceAddFrameResult < 0)
            {
            }

            int bufferSinkGetFrameResult = ffmpeg.av_buffersink_get_frame(m_aBufferSinkFilterContext, returnFilteredFrame);
            if (bufferSinkGetFrameResult < 0 && bufferSinkGetFrameResult != -EAGAIN)
            {
            }
        }

        return returnFilteredFrame;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Cleanup(m_filterGraph);
    }

    #region Private Properties

    private AVCodecContext* CodecContext { get; set; }
    private AVStream* Stream { get; set; }
    private float Volume { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Private Setup Helper Functions

    private void Initialise()
    {
        m_filterGraph = GetAllocatedFilterGraph();

        string aBufferFilterArguments = string.Format("sample_fmt={0}:channel_layout={1}:sample_rate={2}:time_base={3}/{4}",
            (int)CodecContext->sample_fmt,
            CodecContext->channel_layout,
            CodecContext->sample_rate,
            Stream->time_base.num,
            Stream->time_base.den);

        AVFilterContext* aBufferSourceFilterContext = CreateFilter("abuffer", m_filterGraph, aBufferFilterArguments);
        AVFilterContext* volumeFilterContext = CreateFilter("volume", m_filterGraph, string.Format("volume={0}", Volume));
        AVFilterContext* aBufferSinkFilterContext = CreateFilter("abuffersink", m_filterGraph);

        LinkFilter(aBufferSourceFilterContext, volumeFilterContext);
        LinkFilter(volumeFilterContext, aBufferSinkFilterContext);

        SetFilterGraphConfiguration(m_filterGraph, null);

        m_aBufferSourceFilterContext = aBufferSourceFilterContext;
        m_aBufferSinkFilterContext = aBufferSinkFilterContext;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Private Cleanup Helper Functions

    private static void Cleanup(AVFilterGraph* filterGraph)
    {
        if (filterGraph != null)
        {
            ffmpeg.avfilter_graph_free(&filterGraph);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Provate Helpers

    private AVFilterGraph* GetAllocatedFilterGraph()
    {
        AVFilterGraph* filterGraph = ffmpeg.avfilter_graph_alloc();
        if (filterGraph == null)
        {
        }

        return filterGraph;
    }

    private AVFilter* GetFilterByName(string name)
    {
        AVFilter* filter = ffmpeg.avfilter_get_by_name(name);
        if (filter == null)
        {
        }

        return filter;
    }

    private void SetFilterGraphConfiguration(AVFilterGraph* filterGraph, void* logContext)
    {
        int filterGraphConfigResult = ffmpeg.avfilter_graph_config(filterGraph, logContext);
        if (filterGraphConfigResult < 0)
        {
        }
    }

    private AVFilterContext* CreateFilter(string filterName, AVFilterGraph* filterGraph, string filterArguments = null)
    {
        AVFilter* filter = GetFilterByName(filterName);
        AVFilterContext* filterContext;

        int aBufferFilterCreateResult = ffmpeg.avfilter_graph_create_filter(&filterContext, filter, filterName, filterArguments, null, filterGraph);
        if (aBufferFilterCreateResult < 0)
        {
        }

        return filterContext;
    }

    private void LinkFilter(AVFilterContext* source, AVFilterContext* destination)
    {
        int filterLinkResult = ffmpeg.avfilter_link(source, 0, destination, 0);
        if (filterLinkResult < 0)
        {
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

The Adjust() function is called after a frame is decoded.  I'm currently getting a -22 error when av_buffersrc_add_frame() is called.  This indicates that a parameter is invalid, but after debugging, I cannot see anything that would be causing this.

This is how the code is called:

```
while (ffmpeg.av_read_frame(formatContext, &packet) >= 0)
{
    if (packet.stream_index == streamIndex)
    {
        while (packet.size > 0)
        {
            int frameDecoded;
            int frameDecodedResult = ffmpeg.avcodec_decode_audio4(codecContext, frame, &frameDecoded, packet);

            if (frameDecoded > 0 && frameDecodedResult >= 0)
            {
                AVFrame* filteredFrame = m_filterVolume.Adjust(frame);

                //writeAudio.WriteFrame(filteredFrame);

                packet.data += totalBytesDecoded;
                packet.size -= totalBytesDecoded;
            }
        }

        frameIndex++;
    }

    Avcodec.av_free_packet(&packet);
}
```

**Update 2:**

Cracked it.  The "channel_layout" option in the filter argument string is supposed to be a hexadecimal.  This is what the string formatting should look like:

```
string aBufferFilterArguments = string.Format("sample_fmt={0}:channel_layout=0x{1}:sample_rate={2}:time_base={3}/{4}",
    (int)CodecContext->sample_fmt,
    CodecContext->channel_layout,
    CodecContext->sample_rate,
    Stream->time_base.num,
    Stream->time_base.den);
```

Comment: Which wrapper do you use ?

Comment: Using the FFmpeg.AutoGen project

Comment: You need to pass the frames to the "volume" audio filter (with the "volume" dictionary key set to the value you need), something similar to what's done here: https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/filter_audio.c

Comment: I guess it should be channel_layout=0x{1:X} then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is build a filter graph and process the audio stream through that graph. In your case, the graph is just INPUT ("abuffer") -> VOLUME -> OUTPUT ("abuffersink").
Here is a sample console app that demonstrates that. It's loosely based on ffmpeg samples  [filtering_audio](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/filtering_audio.c), [filter_audio](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/filter_audio.c) and [remuxing](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/remuxing.c).

You can use it like this:

```
ChangeVolume.exe http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4 bunny_half.mp4 0.5
```

And here is the code:

```
class Program
{
    static unsafe void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(@"Current directory: " + Environment.CurrentDirectory);
        Console.WriteLine(@"Running in {0}-bit mode.", Environment.Is64BitProcess ? @"64" : @"32");

        // adapt this to your context
        var ffmpegPath = string.Format(@"../../../FFmpeg/bin/{0}", Environment.Is64BitProcess ? @"x64" : @"x86");
        InteropHelper.SetDllDirectory(ffmpegPath);

        int ret, i;
        if (args.Length < 3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("usage: ChangeVolume input output <volume ratio>");
            return;
        }

        string in_filename = args[0];
        string out_filename = args[1];
        double ratio = double.Parse(args[2]); 
        ffmpeg.av_register_all();
        ffmpeg.avfilter_register_all();

        // open input file
        AVFormatContext* ifmt_ctx = null;
        InteropHelper.Check(ffmpeg.avformat_open_input(&ifmt_ctx, in_filename, null, null));

        // dump input
        ffmpeg.av_dump_format(ifmt_ctx, 0, in_filename, 0);

        // get streams info to determine audio stream index
        InteropHelper.Check(ffmpeg.avformat_find_stream_info(ifmt_ctx, null));

        // determine input decoder
        AVCodec* dec;
        int audio_stream_index = ffmpeg.av_find_best_stream(ifmt_ctx, AVMediaType.AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO, -1, -1, &dec, 0);
        AVCodecContext* dec_ctx = ifmt_ctx->streams[audio_stream_index]->codec;

        // open input decoder
        InteropHelper.Check(ffmpeg.avcodec_open2(dec_ctx, dec, null));

        // build a filter graph
        AVFilterContext* buffersrc_ctx;
        AVFilterContext* buffersink_ctx;
        AVFilterGraph* filter_graph = init_filter_graph(ifmt_ctx, dec_ctx, audio_stream_index, &buffersrc_ctx, &buffersink_ctx, ratio);

        // prepare output
        AVFormatContext* ofmt_ctx = null;
        InteropHelper.Check(ffmpeg.avformat_alloc_output_context2(&ofmt_ctx, null, null, out_filename));
        InteropHelper.Check(ofmt_ctx);

        // create output streams
        AVCodecContext* enc_ctx = null;
        ofmt_ctx->oformat->flags |= InteropHelper.AVFMT_NOTIMESTAMPS;
        for (i = 0; i < ifmt_ctx->nb_streams; i++)
        {
            AVStream* in_stream = ifmt_ctx->streams[i];
            if (in_stream->codec->codec_type == AVMediaType.AVMEDIA_TYPE_DATA) // skip these
                continue;

            AVStream* out_stream = ffmpeg.avformat_new_stream(ofmt_ctx, in_stream->codec->codec);
            InteropHelper.Check(out_stream);

            InteropHelper.Check(ffmpeg.avcodec_copy_context(out_stream->codec, in_stream->codec));

            out_stream->codec->codec_tag = 0;
            if ((ofmt_ctx->oformat->flags & InteropHelper.AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER) != 0)
            {
                out_stream->codec->flags |= InteropHelper.AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
            }

            if (i == audio_stream_index)
            {
                // create audio encoder from audio decoder
                AVCodec* enc = ffmpeg.avcodec_find_encoder(dec_ctx->codec_id);
                InteropHelper.Check(enc);

                enc_ctx = ffmpeg.avcodec_alloc_context3(enc);
                InteropHelper.Check(enc_ctx);

                enc_ctx->sample_rate = dec_ctx->sample_rate;
                enc_ctx->channel_layout = dec_ctx->channel_layout;
                enc_ctx->channels = ffmpeg.av_get_channel_layout_nb_channels(enc_ctx->channel_layout);
                enc_ctx->sample_fmt = enc->sample_fmts[0];
                enc_ctx->time_base.num = 1;
                enc_ctx->time_base.den = enc_ctx->sample_rate;
                InteropHelper.Check(ffmpeg.avcodec_open2(enc_ctx, enc, null));
            }
        }

        // dump output
        ffmpeg.av_dump_format(ofmt_ctx, 0, out_filename, 1);

        if ((ofmt_ctx->oformat->flags & InteropHelper.AVFMT_NOFILE) == 0)
        {
            // open output file
            InteropHelper.Check(ffmpeg.avio_open(&ofmt_ctx->pb, out_filename, InteropHelper.AVIO_FLAG_WRITE));
        }

        // write output file header
        InteropHelper.Check(ffmpeg.avformat_write_header(ofmt_ctx, null));

        // read all packets and process
        AVFrame* frame = ffmpeg.av_frame_alloc();
        AVFrame* filt_frame = ffmpeg.av_frame_alloc();
        while (true)
        {
            AVStream* in_stream;
            AVStream* out_stream;
            AVPacket pkt;
            ret = ffmpeg.av_read_frame(ifmt_ctx, &pkt);
            if (ret < 0)
                break;

            in_stream = ifmt_ctx->streams[pkt.stream_index];
            if (in_stream->codec->codec_type == AVMediaType.AVMEDIA_TYPE_DATA)
                continue;

            // audio stream? we need to pass it through our filter graph
            if (pkt.stream_index == audio_stream_index)
            {
                // decode audio (packet -> frame)
                int got_frame = 0;
                InteropHelper.Check(ffmpeg.avcodec_decode_audio4(dec_ctx, frame, &got_frame, &pkt));

                if (got_frame > 0)
                {
                    // add the frame into the filter graph
                    InteropHelper.Check(ffmpeg.av_buffersrc_add_frame(buffersrc_ctx, frame));
                    while (true)
                    {
                        // get the frame out from the filter graph
                        ret = ffmpeg.av_buffersink_get_frame(buffersink_ctx, filt_frame);
                        const int EAGAIN = 11;
                        if (ret == -EAGAIN)
                            break;

                        InteropHelper.Check(ret);

                        // encode audio (frame -> packet)
                        AVPacket enc_pkt = new AVPacket();
                        int got_packet = 0;
                        InteropHelper.Check(ffmpeg.avcodec_encode_audio2(enc_ctx, &enc_pkt, filt_frame, &got_packet));
                        enc_pkt.stream_index = pkt.stream_index;
                        InteropHelper.Check(ffmpeg.av_interleaved_write_frame(ofmt_ctx, &enc_pkt));
                        ffmpeg.av_frame_unref(filt_frame);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // write other (video) streams
                out_stream = ofmt_ctx->streams[pkt.stream_index];
                pkt.pts = ffmpeg.av_rescale_q_rnd(pkt.pts, in_stream->time_base, out_stream->time_base, AVRounding.AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF | AVRounding.AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX);
                pkt.dts = ffmpeg.av_rescale_q_rnd(pkt.dts, in_stream->time_base, out_stream->time_base, AVRounding.AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF | AVRounding.AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX);
                pkt.duration = ffmpeg.av_rescale_q(pkt.duration, in_stream->time_base, out_stream->time_base);
                pkt.pos = -1;
                InteropHelper.Check(ffmpeg.av_interleaved_write_frame(ofmt_ctx, &pkt));
            }
            ffmpeg.av_packet_unref(&pkt);
        }

        // write trailer, close file
        ffmpeg.av_write_trailer(ofmt_ctx);
        ffmpeg.avformat_close_input(&ifmt_ctx);
        if ((ofmt_ctx->oformat->flags & InteropHelper.AVFMT_NOFILE) == 0)
        {
            ffmpeg.avio_closep(&ofmt_ctx->pb);
        }

        ffmpeg.avformat_free_context(ofmt_ctx);

        ffmpeg.av_frame_free(&filt_frame);
        ffmpeg.av_frame_free(&frame);

        ffmpeg.avfilter_graph_free(&filter_graph);
        return;
    }

    static unsafe AVFilterGraph* init_filter_graph(AVFormatContext* format, AVCodecContext* codec, int audio_stream_index, AVFilterContext** buffersrc_ctx, AVFilterContext** buffersink_ctx, double volumeRatio)
    {
        // create graph
        var filter_graph = ffmpeg.avfilter_graph_alloc();
        InteropHelper.Check(filter_graph);

        // add input filter
        var abuffersrc = ffmpeg.avfilter_get_by_name("abuffer");
        if (abuffersrc == null) InteropHelper.CheckTag("\x00F8FIL");
        string args = string.Format("sample_fmt={0}:channel_layout={1}:sample_rate={2}:time_base={3}/{4}",
            (int)codec->sample_fmt,
            codec->channel_layout,
            codec->sample_rate,
            format->streams[audio_stream_index]->time_base.num,
            format->streams[audio_stream_index]->time_base.den);
        InteropHelper.Check(ffmpeg.avfilter_graph_create_filter(buffersrc_ctx, abuffersrc, "IN", args, null, filter_graph));

        // add volume filter
        var volume = ffmpeg.avfilter_get_by_name("volume");
        if (volume == null) InteropHelper.CheckTag("\x00F8FIL");
        AVFilterContext* volume_ctx;
        InteropHelper.Check(ffmpeg.avfilter_graph_create_filter(&volume_ctx, volume, "VOL", "volume=" + volumeRatio.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), null, filter_graph));

        // add output filter
        var abuffersink = ffmpeg.avfilter_get_by_name("abuffersink");
        if (abuffersink == null) InteropHelper.CheckTag("\x00F8FIL");
        InteropHelper.Check(ffmpeg.avfilter_graph_create_filter(buffersink_ctx, abuffersink, "OUT", "", null, filter_graph));

        // connect input -> volume -> output
        InteropHelper.Check(ffmpeg.avfilter_link(*buffersrc_ctx, 0, volume_ctx, 0));
        InteropHelper.Check(ffmpeg.avfilter_link(volume_ctx, 0, *buffersink_ctx, 0));
        InteropHelper.Check(ffmpeg.avfilter_graph_config(filter_graph, null));
        return filter_graph;
    }
}
```

It uses a utility InteropHelper class derived from AutoGen's:

```
public class InteropHelper
{
    [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool SetDllDirectory(string lpPathName);

    public static readonly int AVERROR_EOF = -GetTag("EOF ");
    public static readonly int AVERROR_UNKNOWN = -GetTag("UNKN");
    public static readonly int AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER = 0x0040;
    public static readonly int AVFMT_NOFILE = 0x0001;
    public static readonly int AVIO_FLAG_WRITE = 2;
    public static readonly int AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER = (1 << 22);
    public static readonly int AV_ROUND_ZERO = 0;
    public static readonly int AV_ROUND_INF = 1;
    public static readonly int AV_ROUND_DOWN = 2;
    public static readonly int AV_ROUND_UP = 3;
    public static readonly int AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX = 8192;
    public static readonly int AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF = 5;
    public static readonly int AVFMT_NOTIMESTAMPS = 0x0080;

    public static unsafe void Check(void* ptr)
    {
        if (ptr != null)
            return;

        const int ENOMEM = 12;
        Check(-ENOMEM);
    }

    public static unsafe void Check(IntPtr ptr)
    {
        if (ptr != IntPtr.Zero)
            return;

        Check((void*)null);
    }

    // example: "\x00F8FIL" is "Filter not found" (check libavutil/error.h)
    public static void CheckTag(string tag)
    {
        Check(-GetTag(tag));
    }

    public static int GetTag(string tag)
    {
        var bytes = new byte[4];
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            bytes[i] = (byte)tag[i];
        }
        return BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
    }

    public static void Check(int res)
    {
        if (res >= 0)
            return;

        string err = "ffmpeg error " + res;
        string text = GetErrorText(res);
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
        {
            err += ": " + text;
        }
        throw new Exception(err);
    }

    public static string GetErrorText(int res)
    {
        IntPtr err = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(256);
        try
        {
            ffmpeg.av_strerror(res, err, 256);
            return Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(err);
        }
        finally
        {
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(err);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  av_buffersrc_add_frame() keeps returning -22 when I use this code within mine.  Cannot understand why, I've essentially copied all of your for safety measure.

Comment: -22 is invalid parameter. have you tried my whole code as is with an existing file?

Comment: Yes, your code is fine. I've had audio decoding and converting (then writing) working for ages.  For the arguments for "args", they are built up using in the input file AvCodecContext, which is the same as yours, so not entirely sure whats happening.

Comment: big_buck_bunny is also AAC

Answer (score 13):

I do not know what API you are using, but ffmpeg has a command that allows to increase or decrease audio:

Decrease to half:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -af "volume=0.5" output.wav
```

Increase 50%:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -af "volume=1.5" output.wav
```

or in dB:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -af "volume=10dB" output.wav
```

Hopes it helps you

Comment: No use i'm afraid, I don't wan to use the console.