# Mix PCM data from two decoded FFmpeg AVFrame* objects

Tags: c#, video, ffmpeg, pcm

I'm currently using the FFMpeg AutoGen project (in C# of course) to decode frames from an audio file and add them to a new stream that is being written to a video.  This all works correctly, but I was wondering how one would go about mixing two AVFrame* objects together (after they are decoded).

I've mixed PCM data before but was wondering if FFmpeg had a built in API to do the work more effectively.

This is how I'm currently doing it:

```
short* baseFrameBuffer1 = (short*)baseFrame->data_0;
short* baseFrameBuffer2 = (short*)baseFrame->data_1;

short* readFrameBuffer1 = (short*)readFrame->data_0;
short* readFrameBuffer2 = (short*)readFrame->data_1;

for (int frameIndex = 0; frameIndex< 1024; frameIndex++)
{
    int dataSample1 = GetInRangeSample(baseFrameBuffer1[frameIndex] + readFrameBuffer1[frameIndex]);
    int dataSample2 = GetInRangeSample(baseFrameBuffer2[frameIndex] + readFrameBuffer2[frameIndex]);

    baseFrame->data_0[frameIndex] = (byte)dataSample1;
    baseFrame->data_1[frameIndex] = (byte)dataSample2;
}

private static int GetInRangeSample(int sample)
{
    if (sample > short.MaxValue)
    {
        sample = short.MaxValue;
    }

    if (sample < short.MinValue)
    {
        sample = short.MinValue;
    }

    return sample;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [amix](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amix) filter in [libavfilter](https://www.ffmpeg.org/libavfilter.html).

Comment: Using my previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37570129/increase-decrease-audio-volume-using-ffmpeg and your answer, I solved the problem.